# optimize sql "With ismember Select From query"

Tags: t-sql, query-optimization

I have a query which run extremely slow when "checking is_member" in comparison to just loading the whole dataset. This view acts as a security check, it checks if you are a member of a particular group - ie group 1, then the next column will state what access it has - ie division 2.
This view then is joined with the Fact table, so that it will only retrieve division 2 rows.

The question is, does the is_member execute for each line of Fact data? Just my theory because it runs 1000 times faster without this view. And if anyone can suggest an alternative structure?

```
  WITH group_security AS (SELECT DISTINCT division_cod FROM dbo.dim_group_security_division AS gsd
  WHERE     (IS_MEMBER(group_name) = 1))
  SELECT     dbo.dim_division.dim_division_key, dbo.dim_division.division_ID, dbo.dim_division.division_code, dbo.dim_division.division_name 
  FROM         dbo.dim_division INNER JOIN
  group_security ON dbo.dim_division.division_code = group_security.division_code OR group_security.division_code = 'ALL'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you `JOIN` on `dbo.dim_division.division_code`, do you have an index on this column?

Alternatively you could give this a try:

```
SELECT dim.dim_division_key, 
       dim.division_ID, 
       dim.division_code, 
       dim.division_name 
  FROM dim_division dim
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT *
                  FROM dbo.dim_group_security_division gsd
                 WHERE gsd.division_code IN ('ALL', dim.division_code)
                   AND IS_MEMBER(gsd.group_name) = 1 )
```

This way the system can stop at the first 'match' in `dim_group_security_division` instead of having to find all and then aggregate the result because of the DISTINCT.

In this case, it might also be useful to have an index on `gsd.division_code` to speed things up a bit.